upgrading from usb 3 to usb 4
I was wondering if it is possible to upgrade from USB 2 and 3 to 3 and 4 on a laptop?  If it is possible please tell me the condition that makes such upgrade possible?
because my laptop takes almost two hours to transfer my files (60 GB) from my phone to my external hard drive using USB 3 (for the hard drive) and USB-c for my phone. i understand that there are three devices involved in this process and the speed is really dependent on these three devices but let me tell you that the same thing happens when transferring data between my laptop and a USB flash drive.
I have an ASUS laptop (UX434FQ) and in the information i was able to find it says " PCI-Express 3.0 (8.0 GT/s). I read somewhere it is an important point so i am mentioning it.

Welcome to SuperUser. I recommend that you read the Help section to understand how this site works. One of the rules is only one question per post. Please choose one of your questions and remove the other one. Second, have you done any research on upgrading USB on a laptop? Finally, have you looked into WHY file transfers may be running more slowly than you expect on your system? There are many questions on this site already about that and answers you should probably review: https://superuser.com/search?q=usb+transfer+slow

USB 4 requires different hardware compared to USB 3.2 GEN 1 and USB 2.  They are backwards compatible but without the correct port you will NOT get the faster transfer speeds. If your hardware only supports (USB 2, USB 3.2 GEN 1) then that all it will ever support. There is no way to upgrade that compatibility.  PCI-Express 3.0 has little to do with any version of USB.

How long does it take to transfer the files from the phone to the laptop instead of the external hard drive? It is possible that the phone is the limiting factor.

Generally speaking, laptops in general cannot be upgraded.  Yes, there are the usual common exceptions, like disks and RAM.  In much rarer cases and even the CPU and GPU can be upgraded, as well as some other components that have internal connectors and are designed to be replaceable.
However, you cannot upgrade the USB version of a laptop.  The chip that controls USB functionality is soldered onto the motherboard and cannot be replaced.  Whatever USB version you have on your laptop is what you are stuck with.  Not to mention, even if that chip was socketed and could be replaced, the traces on the motherboard cannot.  Since USB2 only uses 4 lines, USB3 uses 9, its not physically possible.
